# 2 скрипта по отдельности работают, а в комбинации - нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Написал для себя скрипт парсить с proz.com глоссарии для перевода. Пару дней назад работал нормально, но сегодня возникла проблема.

1. Когда запускаю скрипт, который скачивает список глоссариев для языковой пары, все нормально работает. https://www.proz.com/glossary-translations/english-to-russian-translations
2. Когда запускаю скрипт на скачивание одного глоссария, все тоже нормально работает - скрипт обращается непосредственно на страницу глоссария и постранично перебирает его, скачивая.
3. Когда же я запускаю комбинированный скрипт, который перебирает список глоссариев (п. 1), а потом заходит по каждой ссылке и скачивает очередной глоссарий (п.2), то вот здесь и возникает проблема:

   > ```
   > urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
   > ```

Причем этот неработающий комбинированный скрипт состоит из двух рабочих простых скриптов.
Подстановка User Agent не помогает:

`response = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'})`

Это мой первый опыт программирования, поэтому заранее прошу прощения за неточности описания и неполную, возможно, информацию. Если нужно что-то уточнить, я дополню.

```
def main():  #анализ списка глоссариев
    webpage = get_html(enter_link())
```

Здесь все еще нормально, а при выполнении следующей функции возникает ошибка:

```
def get_html(url):
    response = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}) #на этой строке ошибка
    webpage = urlopen(response).read()
```

**enter_link()** - это просто хранилище ссылки на страницу со списком глоссариев:

```
def enter_link:
    eee = 'https://www.proz.com/glossary-translations/english-to-russian-translations/'
    return eee
```

Еще хотел бы добавить, что несколько дней назад этот скрипт нормально работал, проблемы возникли только вчера. Поэтому не думаю, что проблема в коде. Я склонен считать, что что-то подкрутили на сайте. Ранее у меня уже была подобная ситуация. Первый вариант скрипта нормально работал, пока на сайте не сделали проверку user-agent. Я добавил строку с его подменой. Теперь - новое ограничение. Что это  - куки, проверка интервалов прохода скрипта по страницам или что-то иное?

Comment: ``enter_link()`` это что?

Comment: это просто хранилище ссылки на страницу со списком глосариев: eee = 'https://www.proz.com/glossary-translations/english-to-russian-translations/'

Comment: В последней части отсутствуют скобки — правильно `def enter_link():`.

Comment: мб защита от автоматических запросов? в куках ни чего нового не появляется? паузу перед запросами добавляешь?

Comment: def enter_link(): - описка, прошу прощения. в скрипте как надо )

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 404 указывает, что страница не найдена. Возможно допустили ошибку при соединении скриптов. Желательно на код ваш посмотреть, чтобы не гадать

Comment: ```def main():  #анализ списка глоссариев
    webpage = get_html(enter_link()) 
Здесь все еще нормально, а при выполнении следующей функции возникает ошибка: 
def get_html(url):
    response = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}) #на этой строке ошибка
    webpage = urlopen(response).read()```

Comment: @ЕвгенийВ Весь код добавляйте в текст вопроса. В комментариях код читать невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось прозаичнее некуда - в конце ссылки затесался слэш. Sad but true

Прошу прощения за потраченное время